# Arena (Rockwell) simulator crashes everytime I click check model or run

Tags: crash, arena-simulation

I'm using Arena simulator (by Rockwell), in particular the "Arena training and Evaluation Mode" for students.
After using it without any problems for a few months, since yesterday every time I click on "check model" or "run the model" Arena closes automatically. I have no idea what could be the cause (I haven't made any changes to the PC, the only thing I did was to add a new video card).
Has anyone had the same problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix in a few seconds: Just double click on the .accdb file in the same folder as you simulation file and click open on the pop up screen. Then try running your model. İt will fix it.
For details check the link below.
https://youtu.be/V7KvyRtMiho

Answer (score 2):

Arena works with access software, it is likely that the version of access you have on your computer is not compatible with the version Arena needs to work properly.
Go to the unzipped folder you extracted from the zip you downloaded, go to MediaImage, then Redist, then AccessDataBaseEngine and finally install the file found there.
These steps should solve your problem.

Comment: I have done what you said, but I still have the same problem. I have also tried to reinstall the program, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and what I did to fix it was reinstalling. The only thing I made differently this time was to tick on the "repair" option rather than "update" when prompted with the access runtime window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I appreciate the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and it worked.
installed a file called "AccessRuntime_x64_en-us"

Thanks for the solution:)

Comment: please provide more details, so other people with the same problem have an easier time resolving it themselves.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).